# What is the current, popular equivalent of "So be it!"?

Tags: interjections

That nice exclamation expressing resignation seems rather old fashioned, right? The Beatles sang "let it be" 60 years ago, is this still current?
What do you say nowadays in this context, is there any common or slang equivalent ?

Comment: Though "so be it" uses some archaic elements, it remains in common use. (Many, many idioms contain fossils of older meanings, usages, grammar, etc.) Other phrases that are sometimes interchangeable with "so be it" include "That's life", "These things happen", "None of my business", "It is what it is", "Not my problem", "Not my monkey; not my circus", "I'll have to deal with it", "Nothing I can do", "That's your prerogative", "It's done", "What is done is done", and "I'm washing my hands of it".

Comment: Thanks, Mike, what about 'let it be'? Please, your comment is very exaustive, put it into an answer, so that I can accept it

Comment: "Let it be" is also still in wide use, with the phrases "Leave it alone", "Let sleeping dogs lie", and "Don't disturb/bother it" sometimes being usable instead.

Comment: As a kid these days I'd just say "wevs".

Comment: @RegDwigнt,Thanks,  is it an acronym? pronounced like?

Comment: Depends on your definition of *acronym, blending*, and for that matter *word*. Pronounced as written, [wɛvz].

Comment: @RegDwigнt, but isn't that rather different? I thought it meant sort of 'I don't care/ it's all one to me!"

Comment: Sure. Just like the "not my problem" and some of the others suggested above that you said were fine. It is certainly possible to narrow down the answer, but for that we need to narrow down the question first.

Comment: "So be it" doesn't always express resignation, it can also be a more positive equivalent to "let it be so", in which case the equivalent expression in 2020 is ["I have spoken"](https://youtu.be/dumA6TvyoRU).

Comment: @nnnnnn This isn't correct. Saying "so be it" is an acceptance that things outside of your control will not be changed by you (it doesn't matter whether you can or cannot change them). "I have spoken" is almost the opposite: an assertion that you do not accept, or will not accept, a contrary statement to what you've just said.  Or, to use in context: If you want to continue to believe they're the same, then so be it, but I have spoken ;)

Comment: @KrisW. Yes, I know what "so be it" normally means, and I personally use it the way you describe. But as I said, it is sometimes used to mean "let it be so". Aladdin: I want a huge palace with a thousand servants and a swimming pool. Genie: So be it!

Comment: "so be it" ***aka*** **amen** and "let it be"  are completely different. So the title of your question and your comment under the question are not in tune with each other.

Comment: Your question is meaningless without national and social context. Please provide one. Otherwise questions asking for individual experience are not suitable for this forum. Oh, and I don’t find your usage of “nice” very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "I'll stop arguing with you" (like Emperor Palpatine's "So be it, Jedi" in *Return of the Jedi*), you could say **"Fine."**

If you mean "I don't care about this" (like Scar's "Then so be it" in *The Lion King*) you could say **"Whatever."**

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't classify this phrase as an *interjection*, simply because it isn't. MW categorises it as an **idiom**, at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20be%20it

And people have traversed from *so be it*, *let it be* to just a curt, indifferent shrug to express nonchalance.

Answer (score 0):

**It is what it is,** voted the Number One Cliche of 2004 by USA Today, and still current.

More here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3DIt%2520is%2520what%2520it%2520is%26amp%3Dtrue

Answer (score 0):

so be it = amen

This is really very basic.

> "Amen (/ˌɑːˈmɛn/, /ˌeɪˈmɛn/)[a] (Hebrew אָמֵן, Greek ἀμήν, Arabic
>   آمِينَ, Amharic አሜን) is a declaration of affirmation[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20be) first found
>   in the Hebrew Bible and subsequently in the New Testament. It is used
>   in Jewish, Christian and Muslim worship as a concluding word or
>   response to prayers.[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20be) Common English translations of the word amen
>   include "verily", "truly", and “**so be it**”.
>   **It can also be used colloquially to express strong agreement,[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20be) as in, for instance, certainty, to be sure amen to that.**"[3]
>
> **People says amen all the time in that sense. They also say: You got that right.**

[amen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen)

whereas "let something be" as in the song "Let It Be"

means:

let (someone or something) be idiom
Save Word
To save this word, you'll need to log in.

Log In
Definition of let (someone or something) be
: **to not bother** or touch (**someone or something**)
Please let me be. I'm not in the mood for company.
That's a valuable vase. **Let it be.**

[Merriam Webster: Let something be: an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20be)